# display error when loading many components to Jframe

Tags: java, button, components, frame

I have a JFrame with about 10 components (JLabel, Combobox, Buttons, TextFields). When I start the program, sometimes it doesn't display all of them. I tried repaint in different place and problem still there
Any one help me

Comment: Does it work most of the time?  How did you lay these components out?  Do the same components exhibit the problem, or do different components not show up?

Comment: Some code would help us help you.

Comment: Also, could we please see a small relevant code sample of what is causing the problem?

Comment: It happens 1/10 time I load the frame.

Comment: -1 for being royally unhelpful in asking this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general order of code for creating a GUI is:

```
panel.add( component1 );
panel.add( component2 );
frame.add( panel );
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible( true );
```

That is all components should be added to the frame before the frame is made visible.

Comment: Yeah, It works. I think all of you are right. I added "pack()" and the problem has gone. :) Thanks